# Using JSlider to Scale Drawing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

First question ever here. I'm trying to scale a custom drawing with JSlider. However, it doesn't do anything and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. My code grabs a custom shape and draws it fine initially, but it won't scale.

```
class DrawFrame extends JFrame {

    private int CarWidth = 50;
    private CarShape shape = new CarShape(150, 150, CarWidth);

    public DrawFrame()
    {

        setTitle("Draw a Car");
        setSize(400, 400);


        JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, 1, 100, 50);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);


        slider.addChangeListener((new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                JSlider source = (JSlider) e.getSource();
                int x = (int)source.getValue();
                CarWidth = x;
                repaint();
            }

        }));
        add(slider, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(shape);

    }
}


public class CarShape extends JPanel {
       private int x;
       private int y;
       private int width;


       public CarShape(int x, int y, int width)
       {
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
          this.width = width;
       }

       public void update(int x){
        x = width;
    }

       public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
       {
           super.paintComponent(g);
           Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; 
          Rectangle2D.Double body
                = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y + width / 6, 
                      width - 1, width / 6);
          Ellipse2D.Double frontTire
                = new Ellipse2D.Double(x + width / 6, y + width / 3, 
                      width / 6, width / 6);
          Ellipse2D.Double rearTire
                = new Ellipse2D.Double(x + width * 2 / 3, y + width / 3,
                      width / 6, width / 6);

          // The bottom of the front windshield
          Point2D.Double r1
                = new Point2D.Double(x + width / 6, y + width / 6);
          // The front of the roof
          Point2D.Double r2
                = new Point2D.Double(x + width / 3, y);
          // The rear of the roof
          Point2D.Double r3
                = new Point2D.Double(x + width * 2 / 3, y);
          // The bottom of the rear windshield
          Point2D.Double r4
                = new Point2D.Double(x + width * 5 / 6, y + width / 6);
          Line2D.Double frontWindshield
                = new Line2D.Double(r1, r2);
          Line2D.Double roofTop
                = new Line2D.Double(r2, r3);
          Line2D.Double rearWindshield
                = new Line2D.Double(r3, r4);

          g2.draw(body);
          g2.draw(frontTire);
          g2.draw(rearTire);
          g2.draw(frontWindshield);
          g2.draw(roofTop);
          g2.draw(rearWindshield);
       }
}





public class SliderTester {

    public static void main(String[] args)
       {
         DrawFrame frame = new DrawFrame();
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setVisible(true);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time the change listener is called, it creates a new CarShape object, but this has no effect on the CarShape object that is displayed. Better perhaps would be to resize the visualized object... OK, did you just change the code on me or am I imagining things?

Now you're changing CarWidth (which should be re-named `carWidth`), but that's not going to change the state of the visualized CarShape object. Instead give your CarShape class a `setCarWidth(int width)` method, one that changes its state, and then call that method within your stateChange method.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DrawFrame extends JFrame {

    private int carWidth = 50;
    private CarShape shape = new CarShape(150, 150, carWidth);

    public DrawFrame() {

        setTitle("Draw a Car");
        setSize(400, 400);

        JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, 1, 100, 50);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);

        slider.addChangeListener((new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                JSlider source = (JSlider) e.getSource();
                carWidth = (int) source.getValue();
                shape.setCarWidth(carWidth);
                repaint();
            }

        }));
        add(slider, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(shape);

    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class CarShape extends JPanel {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;

    public CarShape(int x, int y, int width) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public void setCarWidth(int w) {
        this.width = w;
    }

    // this method is just messed up -- you're setting the parameter!
    public void update(int x) {
        x = width;  // no!!!
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Rectangle2D.Double body = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y + width / 6,
                width - 1, width / 6);
        Ellipse2D.Double frontTire = new Ellipse2D.Double(x + width / 6, y
                + width / 3, width / 6, width / 6);
        Ellipse2D.Double rearTire = new Ellipse2D.Double(x + width * 2 / 3, y
                + width / 3, width / 6, width / 6);

        // The bottom of the front windshield
        Point2D.Double r1 = new Point2D.Double(x + width / 6, y + width / 6);
        // The front of the roof
        Point2D.Double r2 = new Point2D.Double(x + width / 3, y);
        // The rear of the roof
        Point2D.Double r3 = new Point2D.Double(x + width * 2 / 3, y);
        // The bottom of the rear windshield
        Point2D.Double r4 = new Point2D.Double(x + width * 5 / 6, y + width / 6);
        Line2D.Double frontWindshield = new Line2D.Double(r1, r2);
        Line2D.Double roofTop = new Line2D.Double(r2, r3);
        Line2D.Double rearWindshield = new Line2D.Double(r3, r4);

        g2.draw(body);
        g2.draw(frontTire);
        g2.draw(rearTire);
        g2.draw(frontWindshield);
        g2.draw(roofTop);
        g2.draw(rearWindshield);
    }
}

public class SliderTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawFrame frame = new DrawFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```